# What is advantage of objdump in programming?

Tags: c, linux, optimization, global-variables, objdump

I am learning about **objdump** and know basic about it.

**Objdump** displays information about one or more object files.

Some people told me that we can using **objdump** to **debug  memory corruption, avoid global variable buffer overflow, optimize code ...** but I don't know how to use it to do that?

Could you give me some examples for it?

Comment: You can find all sorts of information about object code or executables from `objdump`, but it isn't essential to programming.

Comment: Wouldn't `valgrind` be a better choice?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so If I only care about programming, I don't need care about objdump?

Comment: AFAIK objdump is not the right tool for the things you mention. Kind of like a fork is not the right tool for cutting down a tree.

Comment: Knowing about `objdump` can't be harmful, but I wouldn't regard it as crucial either.  I've been programming a while — longer than `objdump` has been available — and I've not needed to use it.  There might have been a few occasions where it would have been very useful, but not all that many.  Other people may have more use for it; they wouldn't necessarily be wrong.  For debugging memory corruption, I'd probably use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) first.  I avoid global variable buffer overflow by not having many global variables and being careful.  I let the compiler do code optimization.